# Integrate ssl certificate in browser

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509certificate

I am creating ssl certificate. I used this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        //Generate ROOT certificate
        CertAndKeyGen keyGen=new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA1WithRSA",null);
        keyGen.generate(1024);
        PrivateKey rootPrivateKey=keyGen.getPrivateKey();

        X509Certificate rootCertificate = keyGen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=PTA"), (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

        //Generate intermediate certificate
        CertAndKeyGen keyGen1=new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA1WithRSA",null);
        keyGen1.generate(1024);
        PrivateKey middlePrivateKey=keyGen1.getPrivateKey();

        X509Certificate middleCertificate = keyGen1.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=FastNet"), (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

        //Generate leaf certificate
        CertAndKeyGen keyGen2=new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA1WithRSA",null);
        keyGen2.generate(1024);
        PrivateKey topPrivateKey=keyGen2.getPrivateKey();

        X509Certificate topCertificate = keyGen2.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=Neon"), (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

        rootCertificate   = createSignedCertificate(rootCertificate,rootCertificate,rootPrivateKey);
        middleCertificate = createSignedCertificate(middleCertificate,rootCertificate,rootPrivateKey);
        topCertificate    = createSignedCertificate(topCertificate,middleCertificate,middlePrivateKey);

        X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[3];
        //chain[0]=topCertificate;
        //chain[1]=middleCertificate;
        //chain[2]=rootCertificate;

        chain[2]=topCertificate;
        chain[1]=middleCertificate;
        chain[0]=rootCertificate;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chain));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static X509Certificate createSignedCertificate(X509Certificate cetrificate,X509Certificate issuerCertificate,PrivateKey issuerPrivateKey){
    try{
        Principal issuer = issuerCertificate.getSubjectDN();
        String issuerSigAlg = issuerCertificate.getSigAlgName();

        byte[] inCertBytes = cetrificate.getTBSCertificate();
        X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo(inCertBytes);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, (X500Name) issuer);

        //No need to add the BasicContraint for leaf cert
        if(!cetrificate.getSubjectDN().getName().equals("CN=Neon")){
            CertificateExtensions exts=new CertificateExtensions();
            BasicConstraintsExtension bce = new BasicConstraintsExtension(true, -1);
            exts.set(BasicConstraintsExtension.NAME,new BasicConstraintsExtension(false, bce.getExtensionValue()));
            info.set(X509CertInfo.EXTENSIONS, exts);
        }

        X509CertImpl outCert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        outCert.sign(issuerPrivateKey, issuerSigAlg);

        return outCert;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get output this:

Version: V3
      Subject: CN=PTA
      Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

```
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 149715605396663388497155581351118592252783057689878885069908245260863565430460802412818367358299876634638359780252229696020802479157890788072833261563832108195747251668671703158252511484715904905685624305474923281348384506398192074853448780012281582290111563345678091608497553821391829971480670544649932159013
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: From: Tue Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2017,
               To: Wed Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2018
  Issuer: CN=PTA
  SerialNumber:    337317b9

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647



  Algorithm: SHA1withRSA
  Signature:
0000: 1E 78 D7 F7 3A E6 E4 B5   D1 35 1C 2E FC 53 A2 85  .x..:....5...S..
0010: 61 BD F0 5A 72 D9 F7 11   23 75 80 7A 6E B0 E0 23  a..Zr...#u.zn..#
0020: BE E4 5F DE F1 16 A7 F2   B7 21 BA E8 13 CB 5A 1D  .._......!....Z.
0030: A9 E4 45 ED 89 AE 87 1E   41 F4 47 B4 F7 EC C3 BE  ..E.....A.G.....
0040: E0 EA FC 1F C7 23 0C 8F   3A 84 8B 98 83 B4 7E C2  .....#..:.......
0050: 6F 7A 5B AD F4 38 8E 00   10 A0 30 59 1F A3 09 49  oz[..8....0Y...I
0060: 0E 42 D0 82 D9 7F BF AC   4D 93 BC C5 A4 DC 04 54  .B......M......T
0070: 53 96 B8 7F AE BD 6D BD   94 E9 A8 A0 68 43 DB 30  S.....m.....hC.0

, 

  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=FastNet
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 161657090792555516695586185263084527366349509696556183715928445892937137032979680125036388699182414350510579635688759948023466646898520852479701338811401262991832177452096078586456052551108597559503898191394682820545429625150985217333874981200678761714744624590813783219900274086624205553792352169064622425721
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: From: Tue Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2017,
               To: Wed Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2018
  Issuer: CN=PTA
  SerialNumber:    38004cdc
Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647



  Algorithm: SHA1withRSA
  Signature:
0000: 24 94 B2 08 80 4C 79 5E   66 CC D4 A4 85 CD 28 9F  $....Ly^f.....(.
0010: 1B 80 E8 F9 04 F7 EA F3   78 AB 73 1A 03 59 ED 77  ........x.s..Y.w
0020: A9 C9 2A 7B D1 A8 D5 88   72 00 7F 82 04 8D 34 22  ..*.....r.....4"
0030: 20 E4 1F 4F ED CB 3A 34   CC 2D 85 91 5C 24 DF C5   ..O..:4.-..\$..
0040: 5A BE 08 3E 2E 64 87 E6   28 AA D5 FC 4C F6 FA 03  Z..>.d..(...L...
0050: 96 56 26 E9 CE 1D 7C 60   1B 66 F7 75 39 69 27 76  .V&....`.f.u9i'v
0060: 28 B5 88 8E 51 40 13 5C   94 05 CC 3F 9C 56 4E 27  (...Q@.\...?.VN'
0070: D9 4A 87 FA 0F DE 7F 8C   0A 46 77 3B C0 25 57 8A  .J.......Fw;.%W.

, 

  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Neon
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 101561805201350912995790593526575119513151168158665152335461285366261351789268704157740436057113460399435904858902325860168207278136991174436556015812872375521572209765853124764558849092076972847896755938071801863244158743746567917559665570200348977261495405005075200724506808480138652079420561951562003264931
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: From: Tue Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2017,
               To: Wed Nov 21 13:17:50 PKT 2018
  Issuer: CN=FastNet
  SerialNumber:    5ee7fb6e


  Algorithm: SHA1withRSA
  Signature:
0000: 2D 04 84 DF C6 57 BB 12   0B 34 EF 04 61 15 2E 16  -....W...4..a...
0010: FB 71 F2 4C A0 B5 88 0B   DD CC 10 7D AE C1 AB 54  .q.L...........T
0020: 7A D4 90 D2 DF FD A7 16   E6 AF D4 CF 6F 44 90 7A  z...........oD.z
0030: C6 77 3F 26 30 9B A8 0A   6A 15 17 56 10 FA 64 D0  .w?&0...j..V..d.
0040: 7E F3 39 98 CD 3F D4 03   4C 83 5B 64 73 26 22 B5  ..9..?..L.[ds&".
0050: 0A DB 7B 9A 73 B1 4B 17   45 BF 49 28 F8 2D 01 EA  ....s.K.E.I(.-..
0060: 89 78 8A 90 1A E5 00 96   15 59 B8 C9 3A CA 3F 35  .x.......Y..:.?5
0070: DA D2 EE C1 96 B1 18 F5   ED F2 6A D0 15 8A 61 13  ..........j...a.
```

I want to integrate in chrome browser. When i convert this text into .cer or .crt. It gave me error.

Comment: You cannot convert bunch of text into certificate. It should be in correct format. Try to generate certificate with openssl, or export any existing from chrome and compare your text with it. Also, you doesn't save private keys, so your certificate is useless, even if you can import it in browser.

Comment: @user1516873 the OP only needs do something with the private key on the server. When arranging trust with x509, all that is required is the certificate to be installed into the browser/OS trusts.

Answer (score 2):

You're saving the summary of the certificate not the actual certificate.

For each certificate generated by `createSignedCertificate`, you need to call `. getEncoded()` to retrieve the DER encoded bytes of the certificate.

Once you have the bytes, write each byte array to a file called something like `root.cer`.

Comment: The byte array you receive from `.getEncoded()` is DER encoded. Prepare an output stream and write the bytes.